# convert plain old groovy to JSON

Tags: json, grails, groovy

what's the simplest way to respond in json using grails?
E.G. the following doesn't work.

```
boolean a = false
render a as JSON
```

Comment: JSON is the JavaScript OBJECT Notation, so you need more than just a value. You could convert a Map such as "render ['a': false] as JSON", or perhaps a list of one value such as "render [false] as JSON".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

directly from the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#6.1%20Controllers), something like

```
render(contentType: "text/json") {
    hello = "world"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Grails requires that the target of the JSON converter be something that can be represented as a collection of name/value pairs or an ordered list.  So an object such as a map or list would work.  And non-primitive objects should also work, since they can be represented as a map of properties.

In your case, something like this would work:

```
def a = []
a << false
render a as JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render(contentType: "application/json"){
    message{
        a.each{val->
            value(val)
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use grails.converter.JSON and you can build the json map directly

http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/02/08/rendering-json-in-grails-part-2-plain-old-groovy-objects-and-domain-objects/